# How to generate the links from layered navigation but only for a specific product on the product page - magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I have specific product - "Toyota Corolla Headlight"

It has 4 multiselect attributes and they are presented in layered navigation:

- year: with values - 1999,2000
- model: with value - Corolla
- make: with value - Toyota
- type: with values - Headlight, Fog Lights, Headlight Bulb

It possible to display it as links on product page?

Example

```
<a href="http://example.com/car-parts/?make=6&model=9&year=11&type=18">Toyota Corolla 1999 Headlight</a>

<a href="http://example.com/car-parts/?make=6&model=9&year=11&type=17">Toyota Corolla 1999 Fog Lights</a>

<a href="http://example.com/car-parts/?make=6&model=9&year=11&type=16">Toyota Corolla 1999 Headlight Bulb</a>
```

The basic idea - get links from layered navigation but only for the specific product.

I could not find such a solution.

I understand that it is difficult - but maybe i can start to get the values of specific product attributes as links.

Please help!

**FIRST UPDATE**

```
$attributes = Mage::helper('amshopby/attributes')->getFilterableAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'year') {
        $filterBlockName = 'amshopby/catalog_layer_filter_attribute';
        $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();
        foreach($result->getItems() as $option) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a></li>';

        }
    }
}
```

This code returns all existing values from attribute "year" with the correct links, But I need only the values ​​of the current product.

**DEBUG INFO**

```
    var_dump($_product->getData());
    ["year"]=> string(8) "12,11"


    var_dump($result->getData());
    "year" ["attribute_id"]=> string(3) "151"


    var_dump($option->getData()); - not work

    var_dump($option->debug());
    ["label"]=> string(4) "1999" ["value"]=> string(2) "12" ["count"]=> string(1) "3" ["option_id"]=> string(2) "12" 
    ["label"]=> string(4) "2000" ["value"]=> string(2) "11" ["count"]=> string(1) "2" ["option_id"]=> string(2) "11"
```

Next, I will think how to combine the values ​​of each other.

Comment: Basically the links your describing above should work. So I'm not too sure what you are asking. How to generate the links? Please provide more information on exactly what you want to know and what you've tried so far

Comment: You're right, I need a solution to generate the links.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Check if you can get an ID or something. `if ($option->getId() == $product->getData('attribute_code')` then it is part of the product

Comment: How do you imagine that? Could you write a code sample?

Comment: I don't have the extension and it's paid so you're on your own on this one. but that if statement should be in the loop

Comment: Actually this is a good question and I dont think it should be closed !!! @LeMatmasta : Please dont ask a question twice here. Please remove the second duplicate questoion http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43484/how-to-get-certain-filter-as-link-of-layered-navigation-on-product-view-page-b/

Comment: programmer_rkt - I will be glad - if you can help in my question.

Comment: `if ($option->getId() == $product->getData('attribute_code')` - does not work. Maybe there are other options - define affiliation to the product ?

Comment: @LeMatmasta use `var_dump($option->getData());` to see what data is available. I'm doing this from the head so not 100% sure. could also be getOptionId

Comment: It's rather more attribute_id instead of attribute_code: `if ($option->getId() == $product->getData('attribute_id')` would be my guess.

Comment: @sander-mangel, function var_dump($option->getData()); return white page, but var_dump($option->getOptionId()); return - string(2) "10" string(2) "11" string(2) "12" string(2) "13" string(2) "14" - it`s all values, but product has only "12" and "13".

Answer (score 1):

This should skip all options except the ones in the product

```
$product = // load the current product here
$attributes = Mage::helper('amshopby/attributes')->getFilterableAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'year') {
        $filterBlockName = 'amshopby/catalog_layer_filter_attribute';
        $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();
        foreach($result->getItems() as $option) {
            if (!in_array($option->getOptionId(), explode(',', (string)$product->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode()))) continue;

            echo '<li><a href="'.$option->getUrl() . '">'.$option->getLabel().'</a></li>';

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With `$product = Mage::registry('current_product');` do not display any results.

Comment: You will have to do some debugging. Check what kind of data is returned to figure out whats wrong. Since I dont have the extension I'm guessing here. Would love to give you a ready to go example but thats just not possible

Comment: what phtml file are you working in

Comment: /template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: The product is available via `$_product = $this->getProduct();` so you can use the `$_product` variable

Comment: But this code returns the two correct values (1999,2000) `$display_year = $_product->getAttributeText('year');
    echo (is_array($display_year)) ? implode(', ', $display_year) : $display_year;`

Comment: I've made an edit which should work using in_array and an explode.

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working. I updated the debug information.

Comment: Sorry but I'm out of options, you will need to debug some yourself. it's impossible for me to do this via comments. I can't reproduce it.